# What is the fastest way to check recursively for changes in a Git working copy with jgit?

Tags: java, jgit

I need to check a part of a Git working copy for changes (recursively), including untracked files. This is what I am using so far:

```
public Status getStatus(String[] paths) throws NoWorkTreeException, GitAPIException {
    StatusCommand cmd = git.status();
    Arrays.asList(paths).forEach((p) -> {
        if (!p.isEmpty()) {
            cmd.addPath(p);
        }
    });
    return cmd.call();
}
```

and then I check the returned status using

```
public isModifed(Status status) {
    return (status.hasUncommittedChanges() ||
        status.getUntracked().isEmpty() ||
        status.getUntrackedFolders().isEmpty());
}
```

What I want to know is: Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge this is the fastest/only way that the higher-level JGit API offers.

If you need a fester way, you could possibly gain some speed by buffering results from earlier modified-calculations - given that your use case is suitable therefore. And you would have to use lower-level JGit API and implement most of what the `StatusCommand` does yourself.

For example, iterate of the sub-tree of the work directory and compute object-ids (SHA-1 hashes) for the files therein. Then iterate over the same paths of the repository and collect the object-ids. Both sets of object-ids could be used to determined if a file was modified and could be buffered and invalidated only when there are changes to either the repository or the work tree.